# Toast after a DialogAlert

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to show a toast after a AlertDialog in my application but I don't have sucess!

```
 public class DeletePatient extends ListActivity{

 private String[] listItems;

    private static final int DIALOG_YES_NO_MESSAGE = 1;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.deletepatient);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems=new Patient().seePatient()));  
 }

 @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

      showDialog(DIALOG_YES_NO_MESSAGE);

      }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_YES_NO_MESSAGE:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(DeletePatient.this)

                .setTitle(R.string.deletepatient)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something to display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);                    
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                    }
                })
                .create();
        }
  return null;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something to display",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

There is no `show()` called on the Toast. Change your code.